# PDF Resume In Latex: text is extracted wrong

Tags: cv, copy-paste

I have typed up my resume in Latex and have used `pdflatex` to generate the pdf of it. I have submitted this to job sites and resume critique sites. Most of them have shown me the plain text representation and it looks pretty garbled as a whole. Luckily I have been able to edit the plain text on some of the sites but some don't let me edit it and I can only imagine what get passed on.

I have my resume code at the end of this post but here is an image of the pdf rendering:

[image: Resume]

Here is the output that is the same for several job posting sites, which appears to be the same if I just highlighted and copy and pasted the text in the pdf document.

```
Jesse Millwood
Objective:
S CHOOL P ROJECTS
Grand Valley State University
B.S Electrical Engineering Degree
Grand Rapids, Michigan
W ORK E XPERIENCE
May 2013 - December 2014
M AGNUM E NGINEERING , LLC, G RAND R APIDS , MI
EE Co-Op Student
A wide variety of projects were worked on from
SEPIC power regulators, refurbishing a stencil
printer from the 80s, to creating new control elec-
tronics for a board washer. Most of the projects
were internal to the company and focused on
building and improving Electrical Engineering
skills. Eagle, LTspice, and the Atmel toolchain
were used extensively
January 2011 – November 2011
C USTOM E LECTRONICS I NC ., G RAND R APIDS , MI
EE Intern
Projects that were worked on included work
on the instrumentation for scientific buoys and
replica guitar pedals for the Circus Freak com-
pany. However, Custom Electronics is now de-
funct.
P ROFESSIONAL S KILLS
Code
(810) 280 0317
millwooj@mail.gvsu.edu
To obtain a career position in the field of Electrical Engineering where the design skills
obtained in school and co-op experiences may be expanded upon, honed, and mastered
E DUCATION
Graduated:
July 2015
C, Verilog, Python, Bash, Make, GNU
Octave/MATLAB, SciLab, Mathemat-
ica, L A TEX, Emacs
EDA Tools
KiCAD, Qucs, CadSoft Eagle, Altium,
Hyper Lynx, LTspice, ngSpice
Machines
Quad PnP, Haas CNC, Makerbot 3d
Printer, Ace Selective Solderer
μControllers PIC(16F),
AVR(mega,tiny),
ARM
M3/4, Xilinx Spartan 6
OS
Linux, Windows
Marble
Sorter
A custom ATmega 328 board was
spun to detect the color of a mar-
ble with an IR LED. This controlled
a servo to sort marbles.
Audio
A 3 channel audio mixer was built
Mixer
and fed a TI D-Class amplifier. The
analog filters were controlled with
some MAXIM ICs and ATtinys. Ev-
erything was assembled on a custom
PCB
Verilog
A simple 8-bit micro controller was
μController built for a Xilinx Spartan 6 FPGA.
Six assembly instructions were im-
plemented on the controller. A simple
assembler was written in Python to
aid in assembly instruction creation.
Solar
A circuit was designed to charge a Li-
Charger
Po battery and make measurements
that were visible on a webpage that
it served over WIFI. The circuit also
included a Freescale ARM microcon-
troller. An MPPT IC was also used.
P ERSONAL P ROJECTS
Mitten
Heater
A mitten heater centered around an
ATmega 328 was made for an elec-
tronic design competition hosted by
Hackaday
Longboard Created a vacuum press out of acces-
sible materials to form a 7-ply long-
board out of Canadian Maple wood
Motorcycle A custom hard-tail motorcycle was
built from the ground up with a
Yamaha XS360 as a drive train
donor. The rest of the parts are ei-
ther custom, Harley, or Suzuki
Guitars
I have made a few solid body guitars
from scratch
Fuzz
As a first electronics project in high
Pedal
school this was a simple fuzz cir-
cuit and a custom made circuit board
etched with ferric chloride
```

The biggest issues seem to be with the headings which are just in a `textsc{}`, which is in a `makebox`(so that the underline spans the column). I didn't think this should cause a large problem. 
Also it seems that the multicols where kind of squashed.

Any help or suggestions regarding formatting so that it is easier for other programs to extract text would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Jesse

Here is the source:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bookman}

% Page Geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=0.4in, right=0.4in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.4in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
% Colors
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\color[HTML]{303030}
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\definecolor{headercolor}{HTML}{801010}
\definecolor{infocol}{HTML}{F5DD9D}
% New Commands
\newcommand{\cvHead}[1]{\underline{\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{\textcolor{headercolor}{\Large \textsc{#1}}  }}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace*{.1\baselineskip}

\Huge Jesse Millwood

\vspace*{0.8\baselineskip}

\columnbreak
\vfill
\normalsize
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black!0, colback=infocol!90]
\begin{tabular}{c | p{0.95\columnwidth}}
%\HandPencilLeft & Grand Rapids, MI \\
\Phone & (810) 280 0317 \\
\Envelope & \href{mailto:millwooj@mail.gvsu.edu}{millwooj@mail.gvsu.edu} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}

\begin{tabular}{r p{0.85\textwidth}}
\textbf{Objective:}& To obtain a career position in the field of Electrical Engineering where the design 
skills obtained in school and co-op experiences may be expanded upon, honed, and mastered\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\normalsize
\cvHead{Education} \newline \newline
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\columnwidth} p{0.8\columnwidth}}
Graduated: \newline July 2015 & \textsl{\textbf{Grand Valley State University}} \newline
B.S Electrical Engineering Degree \newline
Grand Rapids, Michigan \newline
\end{tabular}
\cvHead{Work Experience} \newline \newline 
\strut\hfill May 2013 - December 2014 \\
\textsc{\textsc{Magnum Engineering, LLC, Grand Rapids, MI}} \\
\textsl{\Large EE Co-Op Student} \\
A wide variety of projects were  worked on from SEPIC power regulators, refurbishing a stencil
printer from the 80s, to creating new control electronics for a board washer. Most of the projects were internal to the company and focused on building and improving Electrical Engineering skills. Eagle, LTspice, and the Atmel toolchain were 
used extensively \newline \newline
\strut\hfill January 2011 -- November 2011 \\
\textsc{\textsc{Custom Electronics Inc., Grand Rapids, MI}}\\
\textsl{\Large EE Intern} \\
Projects that were worked on included work on the instrumentation for scientific buoys and replica guitar pedals for the Circus Freak company. However, Custom Electronics is now defunct. \newline \newline
\cvHead{Professional Skills} \newline \newline
\begin{tabular}{p{0.23\columnwidth} p{0.75\columnwidth}}
Code &  C, Verilog, Python, Bash,
Make, GNU Octave/MATLAB,
SciLab, Mathematica, \LaTeX,
Emacs \\
EDA Tools &  KiCAD, Qucs, CadSoft Eagle,
Altium, Hyper Lynx, LTspice,
ngSpice \\
% CAD Tools & Solid Works, AutoCAD, Pro-E,
% Inventor, OpenSCAD, FreeCAD \\
% Shop Tools &  Soldering(SMD and TH),
% De-Soldering, Power Tools,
% Hand Tools, Wood Tools, MIG
% Welding \\
Machines & Quad PnP, Haas CNC,
Makerbot 3d Printer, Ace
Selective Solderer \\
\textmu Controllers &  PIC(16F), AVR(mega,tiny), ARM
M3/4, Xilinx Spartan 6 \\
OS & Linux, Windows \\ 
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\columnbreak

\cvHead{School Projects} \newline \newline
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\columnwidth} p{0.75\columnwidth}}
Marble Sorter & A custom ATmega 328
board was spun to detect
the color of a marble with
an IR LED. This controlled a
servo to sort marbles. \\
Audio Mixer & A 3 channel audio mixer
was built and fed a TI
D-Class amplifier. The
analog filters were
controlled with some
MAXIM ICs and ATtinys. Everything was assembled on a custom PCB\\
Verilog \textmu Controller & A simple 8-bit micro controller
was built for a Xilinx Spartan 6 FPGA. Six assembly instructions were 
implemented on the controller. A simple assembler was 
written in Python to aid in assembly instruction creation.\\
% Maze Robot & A robot platform centered
% around an ATmega 328 was
% programmed to navigate a
% simple maze with 2 DC
% motor driven wheels, and an
% IR sensor on a swivel \\
Solar Charger & A circuit was designed to charge a Li-Po battery
and make measurements that were visible on a webpage that it served
over WIFI. The circuit also included a Freescale ARM microcontroller. 
An MPPT IC was also used.\\
% Musical Synthesizer & A synthesizer was created in C to run on a 
% TI OMAP DSP. The signal was able to be controlled by a custom GUI 
% running on a computer and communicating to the DSP board over the debug
% interface.\\
\end{tabular} \newline \newline
\cvHead{Personal Projects} \newline \newline
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\columnwidth} p{0.75\columnwidth}}
Mitten Heater & A mitten heater centered around an ATmega 328 was made for an 
electronic design competition hosted by Hackaday\\
Longboard & Created a vacuum press out of accessible materials to form a 7-ply longboard out of Canadian Maple wood \\
Motorcycle & A custom hard-tail motorcycle
was built from the ground up
with a Yamaha XS360 as a
drive train donor. The rest of
the parts are either custom,
Harley, or Suzuki \\
% Music Box & A small music box was made
% with dove tail jointing. A
% Dremel was used to make a
% design on the top. A router was
% used to put a quarter-round on
% the edges \\
Guitars & I have made a few solid body
guitars from scratch \\
Fuzz Pedal & As a first electronics project in
high school this was a simple
fuzz circuit and a custom made
circuit board etched with ferric
chloride \\
\end{tabular}

\vfill
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tested your file with TeXShop build-in viewer, Preview, Adobe Reader, Safari, and Chrome on OS X. All of them gives `EDUCATION` instead of `Education` or `E DUCATION`. I cannot reproduce your question so I just guess. If you are suspicious of `\underline` and `\makebox`, try draw the line **after** `\textsc` is finished. If it is purely `\textsc`'s fault, package [accsupp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) is the last chance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behaviour of PDF readers/scrappers is at best poorly defined and is down to how each one works. Whilst some 'accessibility' support may help, that would still be down to the reader involved.